# Laravel 5.3 - What is the correct syntax for displaying an image from a folder?

Tags: html, image, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to display an image in my dossier.index page (blade). I've already defined an image with the following path:

`/resources/assets/icons/step_1.png`

What would be the correct syntax to get my image displayed in my view?

I've already tried something like this:

`<img src="/resources/assets/icons/step_1.png">`

Or with blade:

`<img src="{{ URL::to('/resources/assets/icons/step_1.png') }}">`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset) helper:

```
<img src="{{ asset('icons/step_1.png') }}">
```

Also, public assets should be in `public` directory.

Comment: Do I need to define this `asset()` helper in my helpers.php (helpers file)?

Comment: @kapil.dev Only `<img src="{{ asset('icons/step_1.png') }}">` didn't work for me :/ I've already changed the location of my image from `/resources/assets/icons/step_1.png` to `/storage/app/public/icons/step_1.png`

Comment: @Doga move assets to `/public` directory as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`URL::to` is generate absolute url to the given path and `URL::asset` is generate to an application asset. So use below code to display image.

```
<img src="{{ asset('icons/step_1.png') }}">
```

See the [basic of laravel helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers)

Answer (score 0):

First, move /resources/assets/icons/step_1.png to storage/app/public/assets/icons/step_1.png as **"Storage"** directory should be used to store such publicly accessible files as per the Laravel's offical docuemtnation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#the-public-disk

Then fire below artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/assets/icons/step_1.png') }}">
```

This is the proper way to use such assets in Laravel.

Now, it should work.